# How do I display a "single bar chart" in a TableColumn of a TableView (javaFX 8)?

Tags: java, charts, javafx-8

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Of interest: the upper right part and the lower part.

In the lower part, there is one rule selected; this rule has: 1080 total invocations, including 274 successful invocations and 84 successful empty invocations. Right now I am displaying the ratio of successful vs total, and empty vs successful.

What I'd like to be able to do is scrap the ratios and instead have a single graphical bar showing the ratios of non empty successes/empty successes/failures, using *the same color scheme* as the pie chart above...

And one problem that I have is that I "didn't do anything" for that color scheme. Here is the code to fill the pie chart:

```
@Override
public void loadPieChart(final int failedMatches, final int emptyMatches,
    final int nonEmptyMatches)
{
    final int totalInvocations = failedMatches + emptyMatches
        + nonEmptyMatches;
    final List<Data> list = new ArrayList<>(3);

    int nr;
    double percent;
    String fmt;

    /*
     * Failures
     */
    nr = failedMatches;
    percent = 100.0 * nr / totalInvocations;
    fmt = String.format("Failures (%d - %.02f%%)", nr, percent);
    list.add(new Data(fmt, percent));

    /*
     * Empty
     */
    nr = emptyMatches;
    percent = 100.0 * nr / totalInvocations;
    fmt = String.format("Empty matches (%d - %.02f%%)", nr, percent);
    list.add(new Data(fmt, percent));

    /*
     * Non empty
     */
    nr = nonEmptyMatches;
    percent = 100.0 * nr / totalInvocations;
    fmt = String.format("Non empty matches (%d; %.02f%%)", nr, percent);
    list.add(new Data(fmt, percent));

    display.matchChart.getData().setAll(list);

    fmt = String.format("Rule rundown (%d total)", totalInvocations);
    display.matchChart.setTitle(fmt);
}
```

Obtaining the data is not the problem, the problem is that I can't find in the JavaFX javadoc how I would display a "single graphic bar" like the above...

Where do I start?

(oh, and I suck at graphics so don't even ask me to "draw" what i want; if more precisions are needed I'll happily give them)

---

**EDIT** OK, here is an example of what I mean:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-stacked

Except that I only need one bar, I don't care about popup menus, I don't want the axes, I don't want the legend, I only want the bare, no frills bar.

Since then I have also modified the output a little:

[image]

The goal would be to replace the last column with that darned graphic which I don't know how to generate :(

Comment: For the default pie colors have a look at `modena.css` there are rules like `.default-color0.chart-pie` or the more global color variable `CHART_COLOR_1`. Considering your other question: I would advise against displaying Charts in a `TableView` (heavy weight components in a virtualized container...)

Comment: Oh and another thing: the selected rule has 1080 total invocations? ;-)

Comment: @eckig yes, 1080; and don't let that scare you, in some other dumps I have, invocations of a single rule go beyong the 10k limit...

Comment: I didnt ask because the number is scary big, but you got a typo in your question, where you have written `1090` instead of `1080` ;-)

Comment: @eckig oops... Good spotting... Fixed...

Comment: I'm wondering if you want the bars scaled across rows.  Should the maximum value in any one row determine the width of all the bars?  If so, you will need to keep track of max, not hard but more code.

Comment: @brian no, that would be per row only, regardless of the number of invocation; among other reasons, the "top rule" will only ever be invoked once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableBar extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ObservableList<Data> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) data.add(new Data());

        TableView<Data> tv = new TableView(data);
        TableColumn<Data, Number> col1 = new TableColumn("num1");
        TableColumn<Data, Number> col2 = new TableColumn("num2");
        col1.setCellValueFactory((p)->{return p.getValue().num1;});
        col2.setCellValueFactory((p)->{return p.getValue().num2;});

        //make this column hold the entire Data object so we can access all fields
        TableColumn<Data, Data> col3 = new TableColumn("bar");
        col3.setPrefWidth(100);
        col3.setCellValueFactory((p)->{return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(p.getValue());});
        col3.setCellFactory((TableColumn<Data, Data> param) -> {
            return new TableCell<Data, Data>(){

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Data item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (empty) setGraphic (null);
                    else {
                        double tot = item.num1.get() + item.num2.get();
                        double ratio1 = item.num1.get() / tot;
                        double ratio2 = item.num2.get() / tot;

                        Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle();
                        //the param is the column, bind so rects resize with column
                        r1.widthProperty().bind(param.widthProperty().multiply(ratio1));
                        r1.heightProperty().bind(this.getTableRow().heightProperty().multiply(0.5));
                        r1.setStyle("-fx-fill:#f3622d;");
                        Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(0, 20);
                        r2.widthProperty().bind(param.widthProperty().multiply(ratio2));
                        r2.setStyle("-fx-fill:#fba71b;");

                        HBox hbox = new HBox(r1,r2);
                        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
                        setGraphic(hbox);
                        setText(null);
                    }
                }

            };
        });

        tv.getColumns().addAll(col1,col2,col3);
        Scene scene = new Scene(tv);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    class Data{
        private SimpleIntegerProperty num1 = new SimpleIntegerProperty((int)(Math.random()*1000));
        private SimpleIntegerProperty num2 = new SimpleIntegerProperty((int)(Math.random()*1000));

        public SimpleIntegerProperty num1Property(){return num1;}
        public SimpleIntegerProperty num2Property(){return num2;}
    }
}
```

I just realized there's supposed to be 3 numbers, but I'm sure you get the idea.

Comment: I did indeed get the idea! Thanks! The only thing I am uneasy with is the hardcoded 0.0 and 20.0 in the constructor :/ I have tried to use an empty constructor but then nothing appears. Drats.

Comment: The 0 is the width, I bind that later to a ratio of the column width in case of resizing.  The 20 is the height, it should be some fraction of the row height   depending on how thick you want the bar.  The row height will be based on the font size.

Comment: Hmm, but then the text is set to null... Can't it be bound to the row's height?

Comment: The height is based on the row height which will fit the largest text in the whole row.  I'll update with a binding.  If you want it smaller I'll also align the HBox so the bar is centered.

Comment: I have tried to bind the height as per your example but I get an NPE... `getTableRow()` seems to return null :( Well, it works well enough as is, I'll see to improvements when I really need them! Thanks!

Comment: That's strange, I get no errors in this simple example.  Anyway I originally just put 20 because I doubted the row height would ever change.

Comment: unrelated, just curious if anybody else sees it: with 8u40b20 I get only black bars, with a warning `Jan 26, 2015 11:26:33 AM javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper calculateValue
WARNING: Could not resolve 'CHART_COLOR_1' while resolving lookups for '-fx-fill'` (all fine with 8u20)

Comment: @fge btw, tried to use a StackedBarChart for the visualization - ran into weird problems, though: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28152250/203657

Comment: @kleopatra I use 8u25 here and the references work. Ideally though I'd like to use matching `Color`s instead...

Comment: @fge - thanks for the info, verified that StackedBarCell indeed does work for 8u20/25 but not my current 8u40ea (which is b20) As to the colors: simply set the styling for the bar as needed (the tutorial has examples for a plain BarChart, same for the StackedBarChart as used in the cell)

Comment: FYI: CHART_COLOR_XX is unspecified - so might be removed from public access in 8u40 intentionally, see https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-39899

Comment: @kleopatra oops... Thanks for the advice... I guess that will be a color picker for me, then, I really don't like too much to mix CSS with Java code unless I absolutely have no choice or/and don't know how to do otherwise :p

Comment: The best way would be to use `r1.getStyleClass().add("bar1");` and then in the css file for the scene have `.bar1 { -fx-fill: whatever }`