# Charts: How to correlate colors between charts?

Tags: java, charts, javafx-8

Below is an example that

- has two charts visualizing the same set of data
- while the data are the same, their sequence differs (in rw code that would happen dynamically)

Goal:

- show the same data with the same colors in both charts

By default, colors are applied by sequence of addition of the data. Can't find any api to change those colors - most probably I'm missing something obvious, what is it?

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.Collector;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.chart.StackedBarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CorrelatedChartColors extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        PieChart pieChart = new PieChart();
        pieChart.setData(getPieData());

        final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final StackedBarChart<String, Number> sbc =
                new StackedBarChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
        ObservableList<Series<String, Number>> barData = createBarData(getPieData());
        // simulate client code that re-orders/filters the data
        FXCollections.shuffle(barData);
        sbc.setData(barData);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Correlated Charts");
        Scene scene = new Scene(new HBox(pieChart, sbc));
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creates and returns data for StackedBarChart from the given pieData.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private ObservableList<Series<String, Number>> createBarData(
            ObservableList<Data> pieChartData) {
        ObservableList<Series<String, Number>> data = pieChartData.stream()
            .map(p -> new XYChart.Data<>("none", (Number) p.getPieValue(), p.getName())) 
            .map(xy -> new Series<>((String)xy.getExtraValue(), 
                        FXCollections.observableArrayList(xy)))
            .collect(toObservableList())
        ;
        return data;
    }

    /**
     * Creates and returns data for PieChart.
     */
    private ObservableList<Data> getPieData() {
        ObservableList<Data> pieData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        pieData.addAll(new PieChart.Data("java", 17.56), 
                new PieChart.Data("C", 17.06), 
                new PieChart.Data("PHP", 6.0),
                new PieChart.Data("(Visual)Basic", 4.76),
                new PieChart.Data("Other", 31.37));
        return pieData;
    }

    public static <T>  Collector<T, ?, ObservableList<T>> toObservableList() {
        return Collector.of((Supplier<ObservableList<T>>) FXCollections::observableArrayList,
                List::add,
                (left, right) -> {
                    left.addAll(right);
                    return left;
                });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: A way to change colors would be to use a stylesheet and set the default color to blue. Something like: .default-color0.chart-pie { -fx-pie-color: blue;} .default-color1.chart-pie {-fx-pie-color: yellow;}

Comment: @XBit hmm ...  don't quite see how I would do that in a dynamically determined sequence in the second chart?

Comment: It might be easier to define a "sort" method for the data that goes into pie and bar so that both fall on the same colour.

Comment: @laune unfortunately, that's not possible - both sequences have to be freely chooseable

Comment: List::add  should be ObservableList::add. After running your code, the second bar doesnt show any values.

Comment: @Xbit hmm ... worksforme: the second chart is a StackedBar with one bar. Wondering what's different in our environments? Mine is 8u40b20/win7. As to the add: it's List api and ObservableList is-a List :-)

Comment: List is part of java.awt, you are using javafx.collections.observablelist.

Comment: @Xbit it's the List from java.util :-)

Comment: Yes i know, but still if i use java.util List (Netbeans) i get an error. Only ObservableList seems to work.

Comment: @Xbit something wrong with ... Netbeans ?.)

Comment: No, it doesn't work for me either.  Change to `new CategoryAxis(FXColl...obs..("none"));`

Comment: Are we allowed to have style classes like .php, .java etc...?  Otherwise you have to lookup the colors for pie and set them for the bar and the bar legend.

Comment: @brian strange, worksfineforme just as it is - what's your environment? Autorange must take care of setting up the category axis. As to the problem: well, that's exactly what I don't know how to do :-) Couldn't find any public api to "look up colors and set them" - care to show an example?

Comment: I'm using the same version as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152250/tablecell-how-to-use-a-stackedbarchart-or-is-it-impossible) .  I'll post a bit of coed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just changed some stuff in the start method (plus some imports I'm sure).  I don't think this is the best way.  I would make a stylesheet in user.dir and write my colors there with names like java-color etc., then use that for the default chart colors.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    PieChart pieChart = new PieChart();
    pieChart.setData(getPieData());
    final HashMap<String, Integer> colors = new HashMap<>();
    pieChart.getData().stream().forEach((pd)->{
        colors.put(pd.getName(), pieChart.getData().indexOf(pd));
    });

    final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis(FXCollections.observableArrayList("none"));
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final StackedBarChart<String, Number> sbc =
            new StackedBarChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
    ObservableList<Series<String, Number>> barData = createBarData(getPieData());
    // simulate client code that re-orders/filters the data
    FXCollections.shuffle(barData);
    sbc.setData(barData);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Correlated Charts");
    Scene scene = new Scene(new HBox(pieChart, sbc));
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    //can only get nodes after charts are drawn
    barData.stream().forEach((bd)->{
        int num = colors.get(bd.getName());
        //eg. chart-bar series1 data0 default-color1
        bd.getData().get(0).getNode().getStyleClass().setAll("chart-bar","series"+num,"data0","default-color"+num);
    });

    Legend legend = (Legend)sbc.lookup(".chart-legend");
    legend.getChildrenUnmodifiable().stream().forEach((l)->{
        Label label = (Label)l;
        Node n = label.getGraphic();
        int num = colors.get(label.getText());
        //eg. chart-legend-item-symbol chart-bar series1 bar-legend-symbol default-color1
        n.getStyleClass().setAll("chart-legend-item-symbol","chart-bar","series"+num,"bar-legend-symbol","default-color"+num);
    });
}
```

[image: here's proof]

Comment: dooh .. how gross - but working indeed, and without dedicated api the only solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Got it working, here's the code:

```
public class CorrelatedChartColors extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    PieChart pieChart = new PieChart();
    pieChart.setData(getPieData());

    final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final StackedBarChart<String, Number> sbc =
            new StackedBarChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
    xAxis.setCategories(FXCollections.<String> observableArrayList(Arrays.asList("Programming Languages Usage in %")));

    XYChart.Series<String, Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series();
    XYChart.Series<String, Number> series2 = new XYChart.Series();
    XYChart.Series<String, Number> series3 = new XYChart.Series();
    XYChart.Series<String, Number> series4 = new XYChart.Series();
    XYChart.Series<String, Number> series5 = new XYChart.Series();

    series1.setName("Java");
    series2.setName("C");
    series3.setName("PHP");
    series4.setName("(Visual)Basic");
    series5.setName("Other");

    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Programming Languages Usage in %", 17.56));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Programming Languages Usage in %", 17.06));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Programming Languages Usage in %", 6.0));
    series4.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Programming Languages Usage in %", 4.76));
    series5.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Programming Languages Usage in %", 31.37));

    sbc.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3, series4, series5);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Correlated Charts");
    Scene scene = new Scene(new HBox(pieChart, sbc));
    scene.getStylesheets().add(CorrelatedChartColors.class.getResource("chartStyles.css").toExternalForm());
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * Creates and returns data for StackedBarChart from the given pieData.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private ObservableList<Series<String, Number>> createBarData(
        ObservableList<Data> pieChartData) {
    ObservableList<Series<String, Number>> data = pieChartData.stream()
        .map(p -> new XYChart.Data<>("none", (Number) p.getPieValue(), p.getName())) 
        .map(xy -> new Series<>((String)xy.getExtraValue(), 
                    FXCollections.observableArrayList(xy)))
        .collect(toObservableList())
    ;
    return data;
}

/**
 * Creates and returns data for PieChart.
 */
private ObservableList<Data> getPieData() {
    ObservableList<Data> pieData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    pieData.addAll(new PieChart.Data("java", 17.56), 
            new PieChart.Data("C", 17.06), 
            new PieChart.Data("PHP", 6.0),
            new PieChart.Data("(Visual)Basic", 4.76),
            new PieChart.Data("Other", 31.37));
    return pieData;
}

public static <T>  Collector<T, ?, ObservableList<T>> toObservableList() {
    return Collector.of((Supplier<ObservableList<T>>) FXCollections::observableArrayList,
            ObservableList::add,
            (left, right) -> {
                left.addAll(right);
                return left;
            });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

and then the code for the CSS file:

```
.default-color3.chart-bar {
-fx-bar-fill: black;
}

.default-color0.chart-pie {
-fx-pie-color: black;
}
```

Now you can change the color of every bar in either one of the 2 charts. If you want to change the color of the top bar, simply add a new css entry

```
.default-color0.chart-bar {
-fx-bar-fill: green;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your input :-) But still don't see how this helps when changing the sequence dynamically by user-interaction (think of the shuffle in my example triggered by the user hitting a button) - might be missing something ...

Comment: If i am getting you right, you want to change the order for the programming languages when a user clicks on a chart and the colors should stay the same for a programming language? Well i might have misunderstood your question then. :) Maybe if you put the series in an array and shuffle that, but im not sure, never tried that.

Comment: exactly, that's what I want :-) Sorry for having been unclear

Comment: probably here: sbc.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3, series4, series5); and change the order of the series, but not sure how to shift the colors with that.