# How to style alternating bars on StackedBarChart

Tags: java, javafx

How can I get the A1 B1 C1 bars to be red, and the A2 B2 C2 bars to be blue?

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StackedBarChartExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("StackedBarChart Experiments");

        CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        xAxis.getCategories().addAll("300", "302.5", "305");
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

        StackedBarChart chart = new StackedBarChart(xAxis, yAxis);

        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        series1.setName("300");
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("A1", 25601.34));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("A2", 20148.82));

        XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
        series2.setName("302.50");
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("B1", 57401.85));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("B2", 41941.19));

        XYChart.Series series3 = new XYChart.Series();
        series3.setName("305");
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("C1", 45000.65));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("C2", 44835.76));

        chart.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);

        VBox vbox = new VBox(chart);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 400, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setHeight(400);
        primaryStage.setWidth(600);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am guessing you can use a loop similar to the one in the last answer. Just add an if statement.

Comment: don't quite understand why you ask the - basically - same question again and again. Also, you still seem to be using the barChart incorrectly - it's for comparing values (across different series)  in the same category: you data is different in both series and category ...

Comment: This is the only way to display what I want. Unfortunately changing the loop did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the same ideas from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60141961/how-to-color-javafx-chart-series) answer. Just loop through the series and if a series data x-point equals one of the data points you want to be red, set its node style.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StackedBarChartExample extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        primaryStage.setTitle("StackedBarChart Experiments");

        CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        xAxis.getCategories().addAll("300", "302.5", "305");
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

        StackedBarChart<String, Number> chart = new StackedBarChart(xAxis, yAxis);

        XYChart.Series<String, Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        series1.setName("300");
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("A1", 25601.34));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("A2", 20148.82));

        XYChart.Series<String, Number> series2 = new XYChart.Series();
        series2.setName("302.50");
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("B1", 57401.85));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("B2", 41941.19));

        XYChart.Series<String, Number> series3 = new XYChart.Series();
        series3.setName("305");
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("C1", 45000.65));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("C2", 44835.76));

        chart.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);

        VBox vbox = new VBox(chart);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 400, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setHeight(400);
        primaryStage.setWidth(600);
        primaryStage.show();

        chart.getData().forEach((t) -> {
            t.getData().forEach((j) -> {
                if (j.getXValue().equals("A1") || j.getXValue().equals("B1") || j.getXValue().equals("C1")) {
                    j.getNode().setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");
                }
                else {
                    j.getNode().setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue");
                }
            });
        });


    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

The other thing you can do if the color will always alternate is to use a counter and change the color based on `counter % 2 == 0`. I am not sure if the ObservableList alway forces the order. I would find that out before I used the second approach.

```
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
chart.getData().forEach((t) -> {
    t.getData().forEach((j) -> {
        if (counter.getAndIncrement() % 2 == 0) {
            j.getNode().setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");
        }
        else {
            j.getNode().setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue");
        }
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting an error for `t`: `cannot find symbol
            t.getData().forEach((j) -> {`